# Socket listening in Python

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I've a socket that I initialize the following way

```
listen_child_sock = socket.socket()
listen_child_sock.bind((self.ip, 0))
listen_child_sock.listen(backlog)
```

I then start a client to communicate to this socket. The first message from client -> server and then server -> client is transmitted and received correctly. The socket the client uses to send to the server is the following:

```
self.send_server_sock = socket.socket()
self.send_server_sock.connect((self.server_ip, self.server_port))
```

However after doing some processing, the client attempts to send a message through the same socket to the server (send_server_sock -> listen_child_sock) which the server does not apparently receive. The expression I'm using to check if the server socket has received a message is the following:

```
while True:
   len(select.select([listen_child_sock], [], [], 0)[0]) != 0:
      conn, addr = listen_child_sock.accept()
      # Do stuff
```

I'm using socket.send to send the messages.

In case it's relevant, I also initialize a socket to listen to msgs from the server on the client

```
self.listen_server_sock = socket.socket()
self.listen_server_sock.bind((self.ip, 0))
backlog = 5
self.listen_server_sock.listen(backlog)
```

Comment: Hmm..which part? It's a 400 line piece of code and I'm guessing putting all of it here would make things confusing...I've added some more code

Comment: It seems like if you could provide more context for the code it might be easier to see the problem. Like more code basically. If the code is in a function or is called via a function, provide the function. You say the 'after doing some processing' the client attempts to send another message. What happens during this processing? What could have changed to make the message not receive? Also, Is there another loop involved that you haven't mentioned?